# Поиск ближайшего заданного значения в некотором списке

Tags: python, алгоритм, списки

Есть-ли возможность улучшить алгоритм поиска ближайшего заданного значения в некотором списке функции get_nearest_value

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


def get_nearest_value(n_value, n_list):
    list_of_difs = [abs(n_value - x) for x in n_list]
    result_index = list_of_difs.index(min(list_of_difs))

    return n_list[result_index], result_index


if __name__ == '__main__':
    delimeter = 0.1           # различные тестовые условия
    max_range = 100000        # различные тестовые условия
    test_list = [delimeter * (x + 1) for x in range(max_range)]

    test_value = 7711.63  # любое число

    print()
    print('тестовое значение:', test_value)
    print('ближайшее значение:', get_nearest_value(test_value, test_list)[0])
    print('на позиции:', get_nearest_value(test_value, test_list)[1], 'считая от нуля')
```

Comment: Если изначально список отсортирован, можно воспользоваться двоичным поиском, сейчас быстро накатаю примерный вариант

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код в вопросе использует `O(n)` линейный алгоритм, что уже оптимально в общем случае.

Можно модифицировать алгоритм, чтобы сделать его однопроходным -- чтобы поддерживать произвольные iterable, а не только последовательности:

```
def get_nearest_value(iterable, value):
    return min(iterable, key=lambda x: abs(x - value))
```

Если нужен индекс, то можно `enumerate(iterable)` использовать и поправить `lambda`.

Если необходимо искать несколько точек, то можно подготовить список заранее (отсортировать его). Сортировка, основанная на сравнениях, в общем случае является `O(n * log n)` операцией (хуже чем `O(n)`). Если ввести некоторые предположения (например, целые числа в определённом диапазоне), то существуют `O(n)` алгоритмы сортировки (без сравнений), например: [Поразрядная сортировка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0).

Поиск в отсортированном списке это `O(log n)` операция (не тестировано):

```
from bisect import bisect

def get_nearest_value4points(iterable, points):
    seq = sorted(iterable) # O(n * log n)
    for value in points:
        i = bisect(seq, value)  # O(log n)
        yield get_nearest_value(seq[i-1:i+2], value) # O(1)
```

See [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#module-bisect).

Answer (score 1):

Реализация на основе двоичного поиска (если список изначально отсортирован):

```
def get_nearest_value(n_value, n_list):
    left = 0
    right = len(n_list)
    while (right - left > 1):
        i = left + (right - left) // 2
        if n_value < n_list[i]:
            right = i
        else:
            left = i
    a = min([(abs(n_value - n_list[j]), n_list[j], j) for j in (i - 1, i, i + 1)])
    return a[1:3]
```

Этот алгоритм будет быстрее, так как ваш алгоритм имеет линейное, а алгоритм на основе двоичного поиска имеет логарифмическое.

PS в `__main__` вы при выводе 2 раза вызываете функцию с одними и теми же аргументами, возможно стоит просто один раз сохранить это в какую-либо переменную и пользоваться ей:

```
print('тестовое значение:', test_value)
result = get_nearest_value(test_value, test_list)
print('ближайшее значение:', result[0])
print('на позиции:', result[1], 'считая от нуля')
```

Comment: В Питоне есть `bisect` модуль, который выполняет поиск по сортированным массивам. Лучше избегать реализацию двоичного поиска руками ([большинство людей делают это с ошибками](http://www.solipsys.co.uk/new/BinarySearchReconsidered.html)).

Answer (score 0):

```
num = int(input())
num_list = list(map(int, input().split()))
x = int(input())

min_diff = abs(x - num_list[0])
index_min_diff = 0

for i in range(1, num):
    if abs(x - num_list[i]) < min_diff:
        min_diff = abs(x - num_list[i])
        index_min_diff = i

print(num_list[index_min_diff])
```

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю использовать функцию **bisect_right** из модуля **bisect**.
Важно отметить, что временная сложность функций bisect_right равна **O(log(n))**

Для корректной работы список должен быть отсортированным по возрастанию.

Данная функция позволяет получить индекс, отражающего позицию в списке. Пример:

```
import bisect

test = [1,2,3,9,10,20,23,24]
value = 8

# index in 'test' (3)
print(bisect.bisect_right(test, value))

# near value  (9)
print(num_list[bisect.bisect_right(test, value)])
```

Для получения индекса или наиболее близкого искомого числа из списка:

```
    import bisect

    def list_check(_list, _value):
        """Вернуть индекс наиболее близкого числа из списка положительных целых чисел"""
        return bisect.bisect_right(_list, _value) - 1
    
    test = [1,2,3,9,10,20,23,24]
    value = 8
    
    print(f"индекс в списке: {list_check(test, value)}")
    > индекс в списке: 2

    print(f"близкое число из списка: {list_check(test, value)}")
    >  близкое число из списка: 3
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]